# Employee with, for, at

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, word-usage

Which preposition would be more suited in this sentence: "I'm a new employee...", with, for or at?
Is there any difference between "I'm a new employee for Company XXX" and "I'm a new employee with Company XXX"?

Comment: I'm an employee **of** the University of Michigan.

Comment: I think they can, more or less, be used interchangeably. There's nothing intrinsically wrong about any of them in terms of understanding the meaning of the sentence. It's more a matter of what you or a particular group of people thinks sounds more natural. Personally, I would say **at**, which is simply what I'm used to saying.

Comment: *Employee* takes only *of*. You could of course, say "I am employed with" and "I work for", but not "employee for" or "employee with".

Comment: I agree that they all sound OK. But "at" would be more natural to me, in this specific context ("new ... at").

Comment: I'm a new [name of company] employee. Short and sweet works in many contexts. new IBM employee; new Apple employee, new Walmart employees, etc. No with, for or at. [don't shoot the messenger]

Answer (score 1):

I am a new employee at (Name of where you are working, i.e. wal-mart)
I am a new employee of (Name of company, industry, or person who has employed you)
I'm a new employee with XX doesn't sound quite right in most situations. In my opinion, the other ways of saying it are more effective, and for should only be used if you are phrasing it like you are employed for a company or person.